# PersianDateCalendar and Exception

Tags: c#, calendar

I have a problem with PersianDateCalendar class and ArgumentOutOfRangEexception...
here is my code :

```
DateTime get = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox.Text);
PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();
DateTime set = new DateTime(p.GetYear(get), p.GetMonth(get), p.GetDayOfMonth(get));
```

for some dates it's working and for some it's not working!!!!
for example when I write 7/22/2006 or 5/20/2006 it throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException... I know what is this Exception and what it means.. but the problem is it's not out of range in real world!!!
is it???
Have I done something wrong?? or is it a bug in class?

Comment: Your regional settings most likely place the days before the month, try `22/7/2006` instead.

Comment: Are you sure that it's `7/22/2006`? It must be between [`PersianCalendar.MinSupportedDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.minsupporteddatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`MaxSupportedDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.maxsupporteddatetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'm sure of the dates... I have hundreds of these dates to show you...

Comment: What are you doing exactly? First DateTime (get) is a `GregorianDate`. Your final DateTime (set) is a `GregorianDate` too!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. It's because when you are converting to Persian date, your result is ..../../31 and some of Gregorian calendar's months don't have 31<sup>st</sup> day. you should return your result as a string instead of DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

check your culture, looks like it treats it as dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: That would not cause an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` but a `FormatException`.